# Advance Search For Find Document with Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development, visual-studio

I have a Document Library that contain large number document with four kind of content type.
My Documents Contain specific column that inherit from content type.
Now I need to design an advance search for my document library that User can choice field and type or choice value of them and so use or/and for search with several column!
So My question is that what is the best way to build this and how?!

Comment: Can you please extend your question with more details and information, I find it a bit difficult to grasp your requirements :)

Comment: No offense, but you need to rewrite this question. I think most people will be able to grasp what you are doing, but it is very difficult to understand. The sentence " I need to design an advance search for my document library that User can choice field and type or choice value of them and so use or/and for search with several column" starts off ok, then completely looses me.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at metadata navigation:http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-HA102832523.aspx - this allows easy filtering of documents in a library. You almost might be interested in making managed properties and using those as refiners. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/07/plan-to-use-refiners-on-a-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have designed a similar solution using jQuery,  the only downside being that my filters will work only for data loaded within the page,

However it is good for the connected filtering.

Please refer to my post [jQuery - cool filter for SharePoint lists](http://sudhirke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/jquery-cool-filters-for-sharepoint-list/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, you need the ability for users to perform an advanced search on custom columns, with the user selecting a value from dropdowns in order to search on using fixed values (rather than the default free-text experience). If that's what you need, you should look at the [SP Search Extension webpart](http://spsearchextension.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.

We had a similar requirement for a site, and this solution allowed us to do it quite nicely. The code essentially replaces the default property selection of the advanced search with fields that are controlled by XML files provided by the solution. It also allows for parent/child relationships within the search parameters. It does require several configuration steps, but in our case the end result was definitely worth the hassle.